# How can I run a PEF Executable (for the PowerPC Mac) in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to run *Backyard Baseball 2003* (from *MyAbandonedWare*). Though I have the ISO mounted, I can't run the executable. It says its a .pef executable (Preferred Executable Format). If someone knows software that can run those files or places to look for them please tell me. What I want is some kind of easy to setup Emulator or Executer for Pef files so I can play this 2003 game.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need an emulator for PowerPC based Macintosh, Mini vMac. PEF file is a *Preferred Executable Forma*t for that OS. See [OldOS.org](https://oldos.org/howtos/macppcemulator/) for instructions to use the *SheepSaver* emulator.

**Caveat:** You will need three prerequisites, in addition to the emulator:

- A working Linux PC, with *wine* installed.
- Mac OS (from 7.5.3 to 8.6). Obtaining this may be problematic.
- A PowerPC ROM (included on the Mac OS 8.6 CD). Also problematic.

See also [PearPC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pearpc/), and look up other PowerPC emulators online.

Comment: Do you know of any ways I can obtain a copy of Mac OS? And I don't really want any Pirate Bay stuff.

Comment: No. Read: See also PearPC, and look up other PowerPC emulators online.

Comment: Would this be a reliable source? https://www.macintoshrepository.org/2448-mac-os-7-5-3-for-emulators-